# Parse Column information from CSV basics

Tags: perl

I have a csv file in the following format(open in excel)
Example:

```
Column A      Column B    Column C

192.168.1.100 172.16.16.1  WWW
192.168.1.100 172.16.16.2  abc
192.168.1.100 172.16.16.3  def
```

I am writing a Perl program that will get the information from column B, and convert it to an URL.

I have tried a lot of methods such as `split`, but I could not get any of them to work.

---

```
my $file = 'file.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new(); while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) )
```

When I was googling for code. The code above is similar as the code I used before, but ended up giving some errors which I could not solve.

I use the following code instead:

```
open(IN, "LogFile1.csv");

while() { ... }
```

Inside the `while {}` I did enter codes that delete duplicate row and do a convert to URL. It parse all information from the csv file. I tried to remove all column except column B and the codes work perfectly in converting the URL. Meaning when there 3 columns of info, converting IP to URL fails.

Comment: Post the code you've tried and we'll help.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a CSV file you can use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.20/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to parse the data out. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'file.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
  print 'http://' . $row->[1] . "\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
perl -ane '@F == 3 && print "http://$F[1]\n"' file.txt
```